# Return single document in mongo aggregation in Go driver

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I am using official mongo driver for Golang: `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo`

**Preface**
In this driver, I could not found any method for returning one single object from aggregation query.
[driver aggregation documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.Aggregate)

**Problem**
The problem I am facing with this is if I have some documents which should be filtered and only first one should be returned, then I forcefully need to get all documents and return document on 0 index. In my knowledge, this is not optimized.
I have only one method for aggregation here, which returns cursor of multiple objects:

Is it possible to get single object in aggregation in this driver ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation always returns a list of documents, but you may use the [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) stage to only return one document.

```
bson.M{"$limit": 1}
```

Comment: But it will still return the cursor. and I need to access it with 0 index. I want to avoid this. Is it possible ?

Comment: Please read the first sentence of the answer: _"aggregation always returns a list of documents"_. You can't avoid this. Use `Cursor.All()` to unmarshal into a slice, and use the first element. Write a helper function if you want to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks for making this clear. I will do my changes now.